# what would be the value of variable that overflows?

Tags: c

```
char c = 250;
c + = 8;
```

In the above operation I am not able to understand how overflow takes place, what will be the value of c after execution?

Comment: It depends on whether the `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char c = 250;
c + = 8;
```

When `char` is 8-bit *unsigned*, `c` will first have the value of 250, then 250 + 8 --> 258.  Then 258 is assigned to `c` and converted to 2 due conversion rules of assigning an out of range value to the *unsigned* `char`.

When `char` is 8-bit *signed*, `c` will first have an implementation defined value due to the *conversion* of the out-of-range `int` constant 250  to `char`, perhaps `-6`.  Then 2 due to addition of 8.

By C def of *overflow*, no *overflow* occurs, just conversions involving a narrowing.

Comment: Oddly enough, the standard takes the position that overflow does not occur in the unsigned case, either.  According to its use of the term, "overflow" never happens in unsigned arithmetic because the result of every arithmetic operation on unsigned operands is well defined as a value in the range of the result type (albeit not necessarily as the mathematical result of the corresponding operation on whole numbers).

Comment: There's no overflow because of the usual integer promotions. "250 + 8" doesn't overflow because `int` is guaranteed to be able to represent 258. There's an assignment back to `c`, which is where the overflow-like behavior occurs (repeatedly adding or subtracting `UCHAR_MAX+1` until the result is in range).

Comment: @JohnBollinger and  Paul Hankin.  Agree on both accounts.  Answer amended.